# combining display:inline-block with clear:both not vertically stacking divs

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class="TheContainer">

 <div class="TheData">this is some text inline-block with clear</div>
 <div class="TheData">this is some other text inline-block but not clearing</div>

</div>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
.TheContainer{
 margin:20px 20px;
 background:red;}

.TheData{
 display:inline-block;   
 clear:both;
 background:yellow;
 padding:5px 5px;
 margin:10px 10px;}
```

I'm using `inline-block` so that the `TheData` divs wrap nicely around their content instead of extending the total width of `TheContainer`. I'm also using `clear:both` so that these TheData divs get stacked one above the other.

However, it seems that `clear:both` doesn't apply when elements are set to `inline-block`. The [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8mk6L/2/) here demonstrates this.

How do I use `inline-block` AND make the divs stack vertically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`clear` is only for clearing `float`

To get the effect you want, put `float:left` on `.TheData`. You will most probably also want an element below those `div.TheData`s with `clear` but no `float` to make sure the container renders with the correct height.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8mk6L/6/)

Comment: Why would you use float on a display: inline-block? You lose some of the functionality of inline-block doing that.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is [the one clear-fix to rule them all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1633170/1888292).

I don't think you want `display: inline-block;` because it's actually working the way it supposed to. You might be better off with `float: left; clear: both;` on your inner elements and the clear-fix on the container element:

CSS:

```
TheContainer{
     margin:20px 20px;
     padding:10px 10px;
     background:red;
     clear:both;
}

.TheData{
    float:left;
    clear: both;
    background:yellow;
    padding:5px 5px;
    margin:10px;
}

/* For modern browsers */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.cf:after {
    clear:both;
}
/* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
.cf {
    zoom:1;
}.

<div class="TheContainer cf">

    <div class="TheData">smaller</div>
    <div class="TheData">smaller a</div>
    <div class="TheData">smaller a b</div>
    <div class="TheData">smaller a b c</div>
    <div class="TheData">smaller a b c d</div>
    <div class="TheData">this is some other text inline-block but not clearing</div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8mk6L/8/)

Comment: Hey, thanks :) Yeah, I agree, it is more complex, but it comes with the benefit of not having to add an extra DOM element. Thanks for the upvote even though you prefer the other answer!